# how to change mysql database code into postgresql code using core php?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using function based database connection and select query also plz help me.

FIRST CODE:

```
function connectDb(){
    //my postgresql db connection
    $link=pg_pconnect('host=' . __DB_HOST__ . ' port=' . __DB_PORT__ . ' dbname=' . __DB_NAME__ . ' user=' . __DB_USER__ . ' password=' . __DB_PWD__) or die('connection failed');

    AllDelete();// Audit Logs Auto Deletion
}
```

SECOND CODE:

```
function AllDelete(){
   $MysqlForLogs=pg_query("select audit.*,users.username from audit,users where audit.user_id=users.id and DATE_PART('day',now()-audit.date) > 7") or die(pg_last_error());
$CountRows=pg_num_rows($MysqlForLogs);

}
```

I am executing the browser it will show on error like 'No database selected' but really i am giving the database name.

What is the problem?

Comment: there are a number of sql builders which provide a uniform interface for various db vendors, one is [Dialect](https://github.com/foo123/Dialect) (ps author), so you use exactly same code for any db vendor to build your sql queries

Comment: I suggest you try passing your connection resource `$link` to `pg_query()`, as in `pg_query($link, "select ...");`. The menu mentions that using the implicit connection can be unreliable.

Comment: It is my side mistake. now i changed all the files to pg_query(). It will worked perfectly.  OK Any way THANKS..